# Why do people seem to get so triggered at the word "plebeians"?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, pejorative-language

While having online conversations people seem to get triggered when the word plebeian is used to describe the commoners or common people. They seem to think its bad or something.

What's wrong in saying that you are a common dude or a common member of the society instead of some elite or celebrity?

Comment: *"They seem to think its derogatory"* Because (today) plebeian *is* derogatory, you're a snob if you say that to someone or about someone, it usually means the speaker thinks he/she is superior to the so-called lower classes. There's nothing wrong with saying a **common/ordinary dude**, so say that instead.

Comment: Exactly, the word also means **commoner** or an ordinary dude, why does the listener have to assume the negative meaning here (one of lower social strata) when a positive meaning (commoner) is also available. Isn't it negative or prejudiced thinking if you were to assume a default negative intention in people instead of positive one?

Comment: I understand that people have been offended when the term was used, that should tell you something. You have two users, Pam and myself, who are explaining that using this expression is derogatory/pejorative but you still don't want to believe it. If I call someone a peasant, that's an insult. There's nothing neutral about the words "peasant" and "plebeian" today. It harks back to the era of nobles/barons/lords and their serfs. If you're referring to the medieval ages, then that's fine. It's a historic term, and the correct one to use in essays, and papers not on Facebook or Twitter.

Comment: [​2. (disapproving) **lacking in culture or education**
“plebeian tastes”](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/plebeian_1?q=plebeian)

Comment: Please give an example of a sentence where you used the term, try and provide the context as well, i.e. what was the topic being discussed.

Comment: Why did you say triggered instead of upset?

Comment: Winston Churchill often referred to himself as a *commoner*, as have other Englishmen of accomplishment and distinction. However, *plebeian* is more associated with the Romans, and although it meant something positive during the Republic, by the late Imperial period it became more associated (in the modern mind) with the people that had to be constantly amused with *bread and circuses*. You could perhaps use it in a way that brings out the virtues of the Republic, which would be creative and original. However, the Republic had its issues too, as I expect you know.

Comment: I suppose it's better than _heathen_.

Comment: Who says ***common dude***?? I'd say: regular dude, normal dude or guy. I reserve common for thugs. And I would use plebeian sparingly and when I need a fancy, Greek-rooted word to put down a peer who is acting like they are part of an (intellectual) elite when they are really just hoi polloi. Even the term **common people** rubs me the wrong way. Commoner is opposed to royalty, by the way.

Comment: Why do people get so triggered at the word 'fat'? It is purely descriptive. (it is certainly descriptive and neutral but it is just as certainly judgmental)

Answer (score 2):

It’s a classism. You are drawing attention to their social class.

In the past, your class was something you were born with and it was very difficult to change. [Social mobility](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_mobility) is still limited, particularly to the lower classes and the poorest in societies where education has a cost attached. By using the word "plebeians" instead of, say, "people", you’re drawing attention to something they were born with and cannot necessarily change. If you think of other words that do this, you’ll understand why it’s a word that triggers.

Comment: Its a prejudiced way of thinking. The word also means "commoner", not just one belonging to the lower social strata. Why does one have to always assume the pessimistic meaning and ignore the optimistic one?

Comment: @PrahladYeri what is optimistic about calling someone a plebeian? Please support your unsubstantiated claim.

Comment: One should consider both meanings equally, but understand that others do not.

Comment: Both commoner and plebeian refer to people in ancient societies. Used for people today, the words have connotations that are derogatory, or likely to be considered so.

Comment: In Britain someone talking about "plebs" or "the plebs" would be immediately seen as offensively elitist and classist.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey All right, can you suggest a modern or contemporary synonym for the word "commoners" (which won't be taken offensively)?

Comment: @PrahladYeri, I suggest you make that question a single word request. They’re quite popular here. Also, offence might vary depending on culture. The UK has a history of social class and evidence remains (there’s still a royal family here and various hereditary titles so using the word "commoner" might even be inaccurate!).

Comment: I can think of a "single word", but it's not English: _Völkisch_. Used by populist politicians in Germany, has "overtones of 'nation', 'race' and 'tribe', used by those wishing to demonize imagined "elites", and very apposite now with Trump, Farage, etc.

Comment: @PrahladYeri There are many examples of three or four word phrases that have a positive or neutral meaning that mean commoner. Just look at how US presidential candidates try to relate themselves to most Americans they are ["fairly regular guys"](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/2020-election/andrew-yang-he-s-running-free-money-all-so-much-n982981) or ["just a normal guy"](https://www.esquire.com/news-politics/politics/news/a37575/22-year-political-veteran-scott-walker-says-he-is-not-career-politician).